# The usage of が particle in linking nouns

Tags: particle-が

This line is a lyric from a song:
「どっかから現れた 感情が僕だ」
What is the が particle here used for?
I've learned that the が particle would usually tie two nouns together as in, A is B, or something to that effect, but I can't see how it works in this sentence.

Answer (score 5):

> 「どっかから現{あらわ}れた 感情{かんじょう}が僕{ぼく}だ」

means:

僕　＝　どっかから現れた感情

どっかから現れた is a relative clause that modifies 感情.

> "The emotion that has appeared from somewhere is me."

It is saying "I am merely that emotion (itself)."  To paraphrase it, it means:

> "I am (only) the emotion that has appeared from somewhere."